# Call function in the controller from a model - codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter, facebook-login

i have implement the php sdk for the facebook login in my project.. and all works with the login except the logout.

how can i write the code to call a function from the controller to destroy the session?

tried a lot of things but can´t get understand how can i do this..

hope that somebody can help me with this.

my model with the logouturl is this:

```
'logoutUrl' => $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl()
```

and the function in the controller is this:

```
public function logout()
{   
     $this->CI->session->sess_destroy('logourUrl');
     $this->load->view('home');
     // do more thing you want to do such as redirect
}
```

Comment: any error given? what behaviour is expected?

Comment: no... dont show any error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the below in your controller

```
 function logout()
        {   $logout = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next'=>'url to be redirected after logout'));
            $this->facebook->destroySession();
            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            header("Location:$logout");
        }
```

You don't need to load the view because facebook will automatically redirect to the given url after logout.

Comment: i tried with your answer.. but when i click at the logout button, nothing happend.. any ideia what´s going on?

Comment: what is the logout button url? are you calling the required function(ie logout)? What is happening?

Comment: @courious_coder .. finally i solved my problem.. with the help from your code the